# Display DataFrame with Math Symbol in column headers in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, latex, jupyter, multi-index

I have a DataFrame which I would like to display with the greek names of the aggregate functions.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
      [["A",1,2],["A",3,4],["B",5,6],["B",7,8]], 
      columns=["AB","C", "N"]
)
df=df.groupby(df.AB).agg({
     "C":["count", "sum", "mean", "std"], 
     "N":["sum", "mean", "std"]
})
```

Which looks like:

[image: Example DataFrame]

I would like to produce something that looks like this:

[image]

I have been able to produce:

[image]

With

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[str(cell) for cell in row] for row in df.values]
columns = [
    r"Count", 
    r"C $\Sigma$", 
    r"C $\bar{x}$", 
    r"C $\sigma$",
    r"N $\Sigma$", 
    r"N $\bar{x}$", 
    r"N $\sigma$"]
rows = ["A", "B"]

the_table = plt.table(cellText=data,
                  rowLabels=rows,
                  colLabels=columns)

the_table.scale(4,4)
the_table.set_fontsize(24)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=False)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', right=False, left=False, labelleft=False)
for pos in ['right','top','bottom','left']:
    plt.gca().spines[pos].set_visible(False)
```

The `df.to_latex()` feature looks like it could probably do enough for my purposes but it renders as a tabular which is not supported by jupyter.

Thanks to Elliot below, something like this works quite nicely

```
substitutions = {
    "sum":"\u03a3",
    "mean":"\u03bc",
    "std":"\u03c3",
    True:"\u2705",
    False:"\u274c",
    "count":"N",
}

pretty = df.\
    rename(substitutions, axis=0).\
    rename(substitutions, axis=1)
```

and with:

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
    border: 1px  black solid !important;
  color: black !important;
}
th {
  text-align: center !important;
}
</style>
```

Can produce

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Unicode characters to get the character headings you'd like, without bothering with `to_latex()`.

If you want the borders you could use `to_html` with [custom options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) to format the table.